# google fusion pipeline not writing to any sink component

Tags: java, google-fusion-tables, cdap

I am new to google fusion and started creating a pipeline where source is a file residing in storage bucket and writing to google datastore. My pipeline runs fine without any errors but I don't see table getting created in datastore. What properties I might be missing?

I tried changing my sink to any random file kept on the same location where from I am reading but it does not work.

Comment: Note that Fusion Tables will be shut down on December 3, 2019; probably not a good choice for a new project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion in CDAP's public Slack support workspace (cdap-help.slack.com), this issue was due to the pipeline being run in preview mode.
In preview mode, the data can be previewed at the different stages of the pipeline, but it will not actually be written to the sinks.
In order to write to the sinks, deploy the pipeline and run the deployed pipeline.